# How to escape fields with "$" in the name

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

How do I query a json document with field names like "$id"?

```sql
SELECT [ID]
FROM OPENJSON( '[{"$id":42},{"$id":43}]', '$' ) WITH ([ID] NVARCHAR(25) '$.$id')
WHERE ID = 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes (`'$."$id"'`), if the key name in the `path` declaration starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON('[{"$id":42}, {"$id":43}]', '$') 
   WITH ([ID] NVARCHAR(25) '$."$id"')
WHERE ID = 42
```